# List all who have exchange admin access?

Tags: permissions, exchange

Is there a way to list all accounts that have Exchange (Exchange 2010, if it helps) admin access ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell could do this.

```
get-exchangeadministrator | format-list
```

Comment: not available in exchange server 2010 ... seems this does not exist for exchange server 2007+: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-2007/aa996046(v=exchg.80)

Answer (score 0):

The management roles assigned to a management role group determine what tasks can be performed by the members of the role group - [View a List of Roles on a Role Group](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638219%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx)